# Database error on creating new Low Search Collection

Tags: low-search, database-error

I have an instance of Low Search 4.4.3 running on an MSM enabled instance of EE 2.11.8.

It runs many Collections happily across 3 sites.

But with a new site recently added, when I go to **Save** any newly configured Collection, it returns a database error:

`Error Number: 1048
Column 'modifier' cannot be null
INSERT INTO exp_low_search_collections (site_id, channel_id, collection_name, collection_label, language, modifier, excerpt, settings, edit_date) VALUES (10, '84', 'about', 'About', 'en', NULL, '523', '{\"0\":\"3\",\"523\":\"2\",\"524\":\"2\",\"536\":\"3\"}', 1503055683)
Filename: third_party/low_search/model.low_search.php
Line Number: 209`

The relevant line in `model.low_search.php` is:

`ee()->db->insert($this->_table, $data);`

Any suggestions for fixing?

Comment: My suspicion is that this is related to updating to 2.11.8 some months ago.

Comment: As a workaround, it seems I can create Collections via MySQL Insert and then edit from within the CP.

Comment: …Though saving an inserted Collection in the CP resets the **modifier** to 0.0. The modifier sticks if subsequently changed in the DB, at least until the next Save.

Answer (score 0):

The error says it's trying to fill in a `NULL` value for the Modifier, but that isn't allowed. Looking at the code for version 4.4.3, there's no way a `NULL` value could be added. Even when I remove the whole modifier field before submitting the form, I'm not getting that error.

Maybe update to the latest legacy version (v4.4.5), make sure the modifier column in the exp_low_search_collections table has a default value of `1.0`, and try again. Oh, and maybe try with extensions disabled, too.

If the problem persists, open a thread over at [GetSat](https://getsatisfaction.com/low), which is better suited than EESE for going back and forth with questions.

Comment: Many thanks, Low. I'll run the update next week (I have things working via MySQL insert for now). Hoping the client upgrades to EE3 soon :)